# Speedup of parallel computation

Tags: java, parallel-processing, google-compute-engine

I ran my console-based Java program using google compute and obtained the following speedup:

- 2 vCPUs took 3 minutes
- 8 vCPUs took 1.5 minutes

I was expecting that using 8 vCPUs would be four times faster than using 2 vCPUs (I have not tried using 4 vCPUs though).  Is this normal or should I double-check my program?

If this is normal, then how many vCPUs will it take to achieve a speedup of 1.5 min / 2 = 0.75 min?  16 or 32 or ...?

I am new to this parallel stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your numbers, it looks like your program is 80% parallelizable.
That means, that the fixed run cost should be around 1 minute. So you cannot achieve a further halving.

- 10 vCPUs: 1.4 minutes
- 40 vCPUS: 1.1 minutes
- 80 vCPUs: 1.05 minutes

etc.

Comment: Could you share with me the formula you use to get your numbers?  I am confused.

Comment: Certainly. You said that it took 3 minutes on 2 cpus and 1.5 minutes on 8.  
Using x+y/2=3 and x+y/8=1.5 solve for x and y.  

That will give you  
x=1 minute of unparallelizable code  
y=5 cpu minutes of parallelizable code

Comment: Gah, I meant 4 minutes for y. :)

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether your program is fully parallelizable (this is where you achieve the theoretical maximum speedup), or it has some sections which are parallel and some sections which are not (which is more likely in a real-world program).

See [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) which says:

> In computer architecture, Amdahl's law (or Amdahl's argument) gives the theoretical speedup in latency of the execution of a task at fixed workload that can be expected of a system whose resources are improved.

Here's a visualization of speedup depending on how much of the program is parallelizable:

> [image: Amdahl's law]

*Image via "AmdahlsLaw" by Daniels220 at English Wikipedia - Own work based on: File:AmdahlsLaw.png. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via Commons - [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AmdahlsLaw.svg#/media/File:AmdahlsLaw.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AmdahlsLaw.svg#/media/File:AmdahlsLaw.svg_)*

Comment: Based on my timing above, how can I deduce the number of vCPUs I need to halve the time further?